# php bin/magento setup:upgrade Nothing to import

Tags: magento2

I searched over Google for the answer, but could not get any concrete answers - I have uploaded Payu money (Payment Method - zipped file downloaded from payumoney) in app folder (hosted at Godaddy) and Extract it and executed the following commands on the server (using ssh)

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

it is showing some lines and then "Nothing to Import"

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

setup:static-content:deploy [-f|--force] [-s|--strategy [STRATEGY]] [-a|--area [AREA]] [--exclude-area [EXCLUDE-AREA]] [-t|--theme [THEME]] [--exclude-theme [EXCLUDE-THEME]] [-l|--language [LANGUAGE]] [--exclude-language [EXCLUDE-LANGUAGE]] [-j|--jobs [JOBS]] [--symlink-locale] [--content-version CONTENT-VERSION] [--refresh-content-version-only] [--no-javascript] [--no-css] [--no-less] [--no-images] [--no-fonts] [--no-html] [--no-misc] [--no-html-minify] [--] []...

then i used `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

then some lines executed up to 100%

then i checked store -> configuration -> sales -> payment method, but PayU is not showing there in admin

then I searched google and found it may be some problem in system.xml for , then when I searched for system.xml in my public_html folder (on Godaddy server) I found multiple files, which I am not sure which is to edit?

Comment: Check this extension entry in app/etc/config.php

Comment: I also facing this issue not editing in admin panel comfig settings in magento 2. pls guide us what can i do for this.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/135498)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/135498)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to verify these things,

1. You have uploaded all the files of extension in proper place.
2. Run these command from CLI.

   ```
   php bin/magento cache:clean
   php bin/magento cache:flush
   php bin/magento indexer:reindex
   php bin/magento setup:upgrade
   php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
   ```
3. Try to login into admin and check.
4. `system.xml` check it means you need to check `system.xml` file of extension which available at this location.

   ```
   app\code\Vendor\Extension\etc\adminhtml\system.xml
   ```